# How to save a part of a network?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have made an autoencoder, consisting of an encoder and a decoder part.
I have managed to get the encoder separated from the full network, but I have some troubles with the decoder part.

This part works:

```
encoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs=autoencoder.input, outputs=autoencoder.layers[5].output)
```

This part however doesn't:

```
decoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs=autoencoder.layers[6].input, outputs=autoencoder.output)
```

the error:

> W0514 14:57:48.965506 78976 network.py:1619] Model inputs must come from `tf.keras.Input` (thus holding past layer metadata), they cannot be the output of a previous non-Input layer. Here, a tensor specified as input to "model_15" was not an Input tensor, it was generated by layer flatten.
>   Note that input tensors are instantiated via `tensor = tf.keras.Input(shape)`.
>   The tensor that caused the issue was: flatten/Reshape:0

any ideas what to try?

thanks

/mikael

EDIT:
for kruxx

```
autoencoder = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

# Encoder Layers
autoencoder.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu',     padding='same', input_shape=x_train_tensor.shape[1:]))
autoencoder.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu',     padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), strides=(2,2),     activation='relu', padding='same'))

# Flatten encoding for visualization
autoencoder.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
autoencoder.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((4, 4, 8)))

# Decoder Layers
autoencoder.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
autoencoder.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
autoencoder.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
autoencoder.add(tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
autoencoder.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))
```

```sh
> Model: "sequential"
> _________________________________________________________________ 
> Layer (type).................Output Shape..............Param #   
> ================================================================= 
> conv2d (Conv2D)..............(None, 28, 28, 16)........160       
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D).(None, 14, 14, 16)........0         
> _________________________________________________________________ 
> conv2d_1 (Conv2D)............(None, 14, 14, 8).........1160      
> _________________________________________________________________
> max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2.(None, 7, 7, 8)...........0         
> _________________________________________________________________ 
> conv2d_2 (Conv2D)............(None, 4, 4, 8)...........584       
> _________________________________________________________________ 
> flatten (Flatten)............(None, 128)...............0         
> _________________________________________________________________ 
> reshape (Reshape)............(None, 4, 4, 8)...........0         
> _________________________________________________________________ 
> conv2d_3 (Conv2D)............(None, 4, 4, 8)...........584       
> _________________________________________________________________ 
> up_sampling2d (UpSampling2D).(None, 8, 8, 8)...........0         
> _________________________________________________________________ 
> conv2d_4 (Conv2D)............(None, 8, 8, 8)...........584       
> _________________________________________________________________ 
> up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2 (None, 16, 16, 8).........0         
> _________________________________________________________________ 
> conv2d_5 (Conv2D)............(None, 14, 14, 16)........1168      
> _________________________________________________________________ 
> up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2.(None, 28, 28, 16)........0         
> _________________________________________________________________ 
> conv2d_6 (Conv2D)............(None, 28, 28, 1).........145       
> ================================================================= 
> Total params: 4,385 
> Trainable params: 4,385 
> Non-trainable params: 0
> ______________________________________
```

Comment: could you print the content of **autoencoder.layers[6].input** ?

Comment: Benjamin Breton:  Tensor("flatten/Reshape:0", shape=(None, 128), dtype=float32)

Comment: Can you provide your complete autoencoder model?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem the other way:

```py
# Encoder model:
encoder_input = Input(...)

# Encoder Hidden Layers
encoded = Dense()(...)

encoder_model = Model(inputs=[encoder_input], outputs=encoded)

# Decoder model:
decoder_input = Input(...)

# Decoder Hidden Layers

decoded = Dense()(...)

decoder_model = Model(inputs=[decoder_input], outputs=decoded)
```

And then the autoencoder could be defined as:

```py
autoencoder = Model(inputs=[encoder_input], output=decoder_model(encoder_model))
```

Comment: the autoencoder is an encoder + a decoder -

so the input of the autoencoder is the same as the encoder -

the output of the encoder is the same as the input of the decoder -

and the output of the decoder is the same as the output of the autoencoder.

My issue is that keras will not accept a layer output as an input for another model.